# What type of literary device is referring to a famous quote in a song?

Tags: literary-techniques, literary-device, songs

In his song Land of the Free, the artist, Joey B., sings:

> And everything I do or say today that's worthwhile
>   Will for sure inspire actions in your first child.

is similar to this quote by Marcus Garvey

> What you do to-day that is worthwhile, inspires others to act at some future time.

What literary device does this come under? Is it an allusion?

Comment: No, I don't think it's an allusion. When you allude to something, you refer back to it (i.e. You're such a Scrooge, meaning you are tight-fisted).

Comment: See also, [writing.se] Good Luck.

Comment: There's lots of possibilities with various degrees of literalness. There's: paraphrase, allusion, quoting, reference, ('subtweeting' = everything but name). @marcellothearcane 'allusion' usually avoids mentioning by name, doesn't it?

Comment: Thanks @Mitch. https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/48640/what-type-of-literary-device-is-referring-to-a-famous-quote-in-a-song/48641#48641